# How to create IWICBitmapEncoder that encodes Icon files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, imaging, wic

I am trying to make a PNG to ICON converter, just to practice Windows Imaging Component, I have run into a problem concerning the `CreateEncoder` function of `IWICImagingFactory`.

```
IWICBitmapEncoder* encoder;
HRESULT res = imgFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatIco, &vendor, 
&encoder);
std::cout << _com_error(res).ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
```

This gives an error in `HRESULT`, with the message "The component cannot be found," what's interesting is this **only** happens with `GUID_ContainerFormatIco`, If I try and convert to Tiff, or Jpeg it works completely fine.

So, why can I not create a WICBitmapEncoder that encodes .ico files?
I was hypothesizing it might be something to do with icon restrictions (because icons may have to be 32x32, 16x16) this could make it less straightforward, i am not sure though.

Comment: From the [horse's mouth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg430024(v=vs.85).aspx): "_WIC does not provide a native ICO encoder_". You might consider writing your own; the file format is not particularly complex. No doubt there are ready-made alternatives for you, though.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that GDI+ does not support ICO encoding either, so there's no microsoft-provided way to save ICO files. I can't imagine why not, but there you go.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will create my own. Why does GUID_ContainerFormatIco actually exist though?

Comment: If you look at the MSDN page it supports decoding.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2289894/7571258) have code to write ICO files.